# how to get no of rows in a database table using hibernate in java.....?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing result paging in hibernate (getting total number of rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600215/implementing-result-paging-in-hibernate-getting-total-number-of-rows)

hi friedns,
i want to know the procedure for getting no of rows in a database table using 
hibernate in java...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

it should give you the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(beanClass);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
((Integer)criteria.list().get(0)).intValue();`